# How to change text color for link in tr element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to change the background and text color when the mouse hovers over a row in a table:

```
tr {
  background-color:#FFF;
  color:#000;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

This works if there aren't any links in the `tr` elements, but when there are, the link color remains black (because of `a { color: #000; }`?). How do I specify in the CSS that links in the `tr` element should change color when the mouse hovers over the `tr`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about

```
tr:hover a {
    color: #CC0000;
}
```

is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: YES. Sorry that was such a newb answer...I'm still learning how CSS works!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tr a{
  color:#000;
}

tr a:hover {
  color:#FFF;
}
```